# Executing sqlplus.exe through Process / ProcessStartInfo and returning error code when PL SQL compile error

Tags: c#, oracle11g, sqlplus

I am executing sqlplus.exe through Process / ProcessStartInfo as below. When there is a SQL error, I get correct non zero exit code. But when there is a PL SQL compile error, I get 0 (success) as exit code.

How do I get non zero exit code when there is  PL SQL compile error.

I tried count from `user_errors`, but it is not reliable as there can be existing errors or if the same package failed again (for same reason), the error count does not change.

```
public int Execute(string installFile, string instance, string userId, string password)
    {
        int exitCode;            
        ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

        processInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory;
        processInfo.FileName = "sqlplus.exe";
        processInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0}/{1}@{2} @{3}", userId, password, instance, installFile);
        processInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        Process process = Process.Start(processInfo);
        process.WaitForExit();
        exitCode = process.ExitCode;
        process.Close();

        return exitCode;
    }
```

This is install SQL file - 1 (there can be more than 1 with same structure):

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE
WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT FAILURE

SPOOL spool.txt append;

@@my_pkg.pks
@@my_pkg.pkb

EXIT SQL.SQLCODE
/
```

This is how I am calling the execute:

```
foreach(var installFile in list of install files)
{
    exitCode = .Execute(installFile, instance, userId, password);

    if (exitCode != 0)
    {
        ....
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Without knowing the package name beforehand I don't think you can get SQL*Plus to reliably exit upon a package compilation failure.  Have you tried scanning through the process's standard output (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx) looking for the text `Package body created with compilation errors`?

Answer (score 0):

The pl/sql compiler is completing with a return code of 0. The result of the compilation may not be successful. In sql*plus, you can see the result of a pl/sql compile by using `SHOW ERRORS`. Like you mentioned, under the hood, Oracle uses  `SYS.USER_ERRORS` to display this information. Try dropping the pl/sql object (ignoring any 'does not exist' error) before creating the object. This should remove it from `USER_ERRORS` giving you a clean slate for compilation attempt.